# what kind of asp project was it created with

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looking to make a change to a web site connected to an SQL server.
as far as I could look at the source files the web page is made in asp with VB (*.aspx, *.aspx.vb, *.ascx, *.ascx.vb - among the file extensions). the issue I am having is that I don't know how was the project created nor which versions were used.
was it a simple web site? or ASP.NET web application? which .netframework version? was it visual studio 2008 or 2010?
the code has no comments anywhere, so it doesn't help me at all.
I tried getting in contact with the previous developer, but he is no longer working in the company. besides the page was created some years ago.
is there a way to recreate the project? anywhere I can look and "guess" which versions I need?
any help is welcome!

Comment: are you able to open the project ??

Comment: is it published copy or containing source files too?

Comment: You can see the framework in the web config file. after opening a web config file from a site that was published i found these.
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

and this :   <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">

Comment: there is no project file. i dk if it's published copy or source files. in the web config file I found this: ` <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
   </compiler>` which would suggest net framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

1. There is a `*.vbproj` file among others. This would be a VB.NET VS project file. You can access the project from the VS by opening the project file.
2. There is no `*.vbproj` file among others. This would be a VB.NET web site. You can access it by opening it as a "web site" from the VS menu.

The latest version of VS should be able to open any project created with any previous version, in a "worst" case the project would just be converted. I would not be worry about the version of the framework. Plus, if it is a web site, it could be difficult to determine which exact version of VS was used to create it.

Comment: I have opened in VS 2010 as a web page, but I am getting lots of errors: error Creating Control. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: frameworkName. looking at the source I have lots of validation warnings: name contains uppercase